# django-cms and admin interface confilct

Tags: python, django

I have created custom index view. urls.py:

```
url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
url(r'^', 'myapp.views.index', name='index'),
```

in views.py:

```
from cms.utils import get_template_from_request
def index(request):
    template = get_template_from_request(request)
    .....
    return render(request, template)
```

When i try to access django admin `127.0.0.1:8000/admin` i get an error

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pk'

because in my index.html is templatetag `{% product_list request.current_page %}` which requires current_page to be in request. I think this happens because django renders my index page in django admin, where it shouldn't. What can i do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to fix your problem is to include the urls of the admin site before those 'index' and 'cms' as explained in [the Django documentation site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#hooking-adminsite-instances-into-your-urlconf). Your url patterns in the `urls.py` file would be something like this:

```
    ...
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
    url(r'^', 'myapp.views.index', name='index'),
    ...
```

Comment: I have this already. When i didn't have `url(r'^', 'myapp.views.index', name='index'),` everything worked fine. Also changing order of `index` and `cms` urls doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Previously i had `url(r'^myapp/', include('myapp.urls'))`, changed to `url(r'^', include('myapp.urls'))` and it's working.